# Real Analysis, Folland Problem 6.1.14 $L^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

> Problem 6.1.14 - If $g\in L^{\infty}$, the operator $T$ defined by $Tf = fg$ is bounded on $L^p$ for $1\leq p \leq \infty$. Its operator norm is at most $\|g\|_{\infty}$, with equality if $\mu$ is semifinite.

Attempted proof - Follows the advice from below. For $1\leq p \leq \infty$, $$\|Tf\|_{p}^{p} = \int |Tf|^{p} d\mu = \int |fg|^p d\mu \leq \|g\|_{\infty}^p\|f\|_{p}^{p}$$ by Theorem 6.8. Now, if we take the $p$-th root of this expression we have $$\|Tf\|_{p} \leq \|g\|_{\infty}\|f\|_{p}$$

Not sure if this correct for the first part, any suggestions on this or the remaining parts to prove is greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, you need to show there is $C$ such that $\Vert Tf\Vert_p \leq C\Vert f\Vert_p$ for all $f \in L^p$.

Comment: The calculation with the integrals is only valid for finite p. Where is Holder being used? I don't see any conjugate esponents here. Everything after the word "since" is unnecessary.

Comment: I see well I am really lost could you provide a complete proof of this problem?

Comment: My answer is complete except for the equality statement, which I have not thought about.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For $1\leq p<\infty$, $$\Vert Tf\Vert_p^p =\int |Tf|^p d\mu =\int |fg|^pd\mu\leq \Vert g\Vert_{\infty}^p \Vert f\Vert_p^p,$$ where we have used the fact that $|g| \leq \Vert g\Vert_{\infty}$ $\mu$-a.e. Take $p$th roots to get $$\Vert Tf\Vert_p \leq \Vert g\Vert_{\infty}\Vert f\Vert_p.$$ This is exactly what you wanted for $p$ finite.

For $p=\infty$, first show that $\Vert fg\Vert_{\infty}\leq \Vert g\Vert_{\infty}\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}$, so then $\Vert Tf\Vert_{\infty}\leq \Vert g\Vert_{\infty}\Vert f\Vert_{\infty}.$ Again, this is what you want.

Edit:

An operator $T$ on a normed vector space $(X, \Vert \cdot \Vert)$ is bounded if there is $C>0$ such that $$\Vert Tx \Vert \leq C \Vert x\Vert$$ for all $x \in X$. Equivalently, $$\sup_{\Vert x\Vert \leq 1} \Vert Tx\Vert <\infty.$$

In this case, the norm is $L^p$ norm, and the problem asks you to show that $C$ can be chosen to be $\Vert g\Vert_{\infty}$.

Comment: For $0<p<1$, $L^p$ is not a normed space

Comment: I am still unclear how to start with the proof. If you have one could you provide it?

Comment: Do you know the definition of a bounded operator? My answer is a proof for the finite p case.

Comment: I do not know the definition

Comment: See the above edit

Comment: I see, so this is not a complete proof right. I need to fill in the details?

Comment: Right ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: ok, I am sort of stuck though could you provide more steps?

Comment: Master, I made an edit to my question if you could take a look

Comment: can you comment on my progress?